# Remove title tag tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, title

Is there any way to remove the tooltip from title attribute without actually remove the title.

I have a link with a title attribute like this

```
<a href="url" title="anotherURL"></a>
```

It is important that the title is intact since I need to read the url from there. All the fixes for this that I have found is to remove the title attribute and reuse it but in this case this is not possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to have a title attribute if you don't want a tooltip? The only reason to have a title attribute is to display a tooltip...

Comment: I need it for swfadress to read the separate url. I could do it with rel tags instead but got problems with IE

Comment: If you want to store arbitrary data in an attribute, then use HTML 5's data-*. Don't abuse an existing attribute with a defined purpose.

Answer (score 11):

It's all about the browser. **It's the browser** that sees the `title` as a tooltip, from the browser specifications and interpretations.

You should use if you want to handle data like that, the [HTML5 way](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) (which you can use in any other document type as it's ignored) and use:

```
<a href="url" data-title="anotherURL"></a>
```

with the `data-` attributes, there will be no tooltip as `title` is not used, and you can easily get that using:

```
$("a").attr("data-title")
```

but, you will need to convert stuff and you said that you don't/can't do that.

you can easily convert all `title`s into `data-title` and clean the title using

```
$("a").attr("data-title", function() { return $(this).attr("title"); } );
$("a").removeAttr("title");
```

(all code is to be used with [jQuery Framework](http://jquery.com/))

Answer (score 5):

As you didn't mark this question as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I'm assuming that you'd be open to a pure JavaScript solution?

The following works (on Ubuntu 11.04) in Firefox 5, Chromium 12 and Opera 11, I'm unable to test in IE, but as I'm using `querySelectorAll()` I'd suspect that it wouldn't work well, if at all. However:

```
var titled = document.querySelectorAll('[title]'); // gets all elements with a 'title' attribute, as long as the browser supports the css attribute-selector
var numTitled = titled.length;

for (i=0; i<numTitled; i++){
    titled[i].setAttribute('data-title',titled[i].title); // copies from 'title' to 'data-title' attribute
    titled[i].removeAttribute('title'); // removes the 'title' attribute
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DQaJK/).

---

References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll` at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery to move this information from `title` to element `data`.

Run this on element load:

```
$(el).data('url', $(el).attr('title')).attr('title', '');
```

And afterwards read URL like this:

```
$(el).data('url');
```

Variable `el` here is DOM element or element selector.